# Read numeric data from file in Java

Tags: java, string, file, double, delimiter

I have to add the numeric contents of the file.
The tricky part is numeric content can be attached too.

For example, the phrases abc123, 123abc, or abc123def should be treated as 123. Also, abc123.4 or 123.4abc or abc123.4abc should be considered as 123.4 If a number has more than dots, then it should not be considered as a valid number and should be ignored.

Comment: Please don't share you home work with us.

Comment: what is the expected result of 123abc345 ?

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: You can use Java Regex pattern to check for the number present and using Matcher.group to find the number that is present. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this, replace with comments to use your own file instead of string

```
    // Use this instead when you want to try with your own file
    // String source = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));

    String source = "23 , 23.2 asf 2asfd 2.3asf";
    source = source.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]+", " ");

    double accumulator = 0;

    try (Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(source)) {
        doubleScanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
        while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            double num = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Found :" + num);
            accumulator += num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum :" + accumulator);
```

Prints

> ```
> Found :23.0
> Found :23.2
> Found :2.0
> Found :2.3
> Sum :50.5
> ```